# How to raise a power to a power?

Tags: math, cryptography

I was taught x<sup>a<sup>b</sup></sup> = x<sup>a*b</sup>.

why is x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup> * x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup> = x<sup>2<sup>1024</sup></sup> correct?

Is x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup> * x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup>= x<sup>2 *1023</sup>  *  x<sup>2 *1023</sup>   = x<sup>2046</sup>   * x<sup>2046</sup>   =  x<sup>2046  + 2046</sup> = x<sup>4092</sup>  wrong?

This is from a RSA cryptosystem lecture on YouTube. Time stamp at 1:08:04 if more context is needed.

https://youtu.be/QSlWzKNbKrU?t=4084

Comment: Your first identity is wrong. Your second is correct, and your third is obviously wrong. You are being careless with you exponents in #3.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk oh, is (x^a)^b not equals to x^a^b? because  (x^a)^b  = x^a*b right?

Comment: The way you wrote the superscripts in #1 clearly shows the computation is x^(a^b). And yes, (x^a)^b = x^(a*b).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **1st Identity:**

x<sup>a<sup>b</sup></sup> ≠ (x<sup>a</sup>)<sup>b</sup>

They're different. And (x<sup>a</sup>)<sup>b</sup> = x<sup>a*b</sup>

---

### **2nd Identity:**

Let y = x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup> * x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup>

Take log on both side:

> log(y) = log(x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup> *
>   x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup>)
>
> log(y) =
>   log(x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup>) + log(x<sup>2<sup>1023</sup></sup>)
>
> log(y) = 2<sup>1023</sup>log(x) + 2<sup>1023</sup>log(x)
>
> log(y)
>   = 2*2<sup>1023</sup>log(x) = 2<sup>1023+1</sup>log(x) = 2<sup>1024</sup>log(x)
>
> log(y) = log(x<sup>2<sup>1024</sup></sup>)

Now, Taking Anti-log on both side:

> y = x<sup>2<sup>1024</sup></sup>